# CSS3 animations when show hide bootstrap 3 offcanvas in media width > 768px

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-animations

I am using bootstrap generic offcanvas which is working fine. However, I want to expand collapse the `sidebar` when the screen width is more than 768px with css3 synchronized animation on both the `div`s. I want **css only method** to do this, if css not working, then jquery also fine.

[Here is what I tried](http://jsbin.com/mavis/8/edit) so far and here is a [fullscreen view](http://jsbin.com/mavis/8). 

 Since I used `width: 0;` and `height: 0;` for `#sidebar` div, it is not animating nicely. Is there any way to do so with the existing offcanvas method? I don't want to change the HTML markup.

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Navbar Tag Removed to reduce space -->
<!-- /.navbar -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <h4>Menu</h4>
            <!-- Content Removed -->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-main">
            <p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle
                    nav</button>
            </p>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap.
                    Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Content Removed  -->
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->

    </div>
    <!--/row-->

</div>
<!--/.container-->
```

**CSS**

```css
html,   body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html,   body {
    overflow-x: auto; /* allow scroll */
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
/*Off Canvas */
    .sidebar-offcanvas, .col-main {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
            transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
    .side-toggle .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -100%;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
  }
    .side-toggle .col-main {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

**JQUERY**

```jquery
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
        });
    }
    if ($(window).width() > 768){
        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('side-toggle');
        });
    }
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
        });
    }
    if ($(window).width() > 768){
        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('side-toggle');
        });
    }
});
```

**Update**

1. When the screen resolution is greater than 768px, the toggle button should be act like the toggling width of both the cols, i.e. `#sidebar` and `.col-main` divs. The  `#sidebar` needed to be hidden with linear animation whereas the `.col-main'` div's width should be expanded to 100% width and vice versa when clicking again.
2. When the screen resolution is lesser than 768px, the offcanvas should act like the generic [Bootstrap Offcanvas](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) template.
3. While resizing the browser, the script should need to check the screen resolution and do accordingly as mentioned above 1 and 2 points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it what you want? http://jsbin.com/yageheruludo/4/edit

I changed JS:

```
   $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
      $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active').toggleClass('side-toggle');
   });
   $(window).resize(function () {
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
          $('.row-offcanvas').removeClass('animate');
      } else {
          $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('animate');
      }
   });
```

and CSS:

```
  .sidebar-offcanvas, .col-main {
    position: relative;
  }
  .animate .sidebar-offcanvas, .animate .col-main {
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
            transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
  .side-toggle .sidebar-offcanvas {
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

**edit**

Before first window resize the animation doesn't work.

http://jsbin.com/yageheruludo/6/edit

Change js to this:

```
   $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
      $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active').toggleClass('side-toggle');
   });
   $(window).resize(function () {
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
          $('.row-offcanvas').removeClass('animate');
      } else {
          $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('animate');
      }
   });
   $(window).trigger('resize'); // added this line
```

What do you mean "not animating (...) after change the duration"? You mean "orientation"?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it's not animating the width of both the cols after change the duration... See [this](http://jsbin.com/zejuji/1)

Comment: Hi. No issue. Now, it's working. One problem is, the side bar needed to be visible when width > 768px. I am going to handle expanded or collapsed state in jquery cookie. I will post my answer as well. Example with cookie as it may help someone.

Comment: I'm so sorry. by mistakenly I gave bounty to another person. is there any way to give it back to you?

Comment: Can you see and improve my answer, mainly scripting part, if I made any mistakes in script? Tomorrow, I will pay more attention while rewarding bounty... :)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is your `resize` handler. Every time the window is resized, you add another click handler, so if you resize the window twice, there will be 2 click handlers that will toggle the class twice, putting it right back where it was.

Should be closer to:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    }
    if ($(window).width() > 768){
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('side-toggle');
    }
});
```

But even that isn't quite right, because it will toggle the class on each resize event, so as the user tries to resize the window, the div will keep changing as they drag the window to resize it.

Maybe what you actually want is:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('active');
        $('.row-offcanvas').removeClass('side-toggle');
    } else {
        $('.row-offcanvas').removeClass('active');
        $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('side-toggle');
    }
});
```

I don't know if that is the entire problem, but it is definitely part of it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I think you misunderstood the issue it seems. Please see my edit where I described the desired output. I feel that it's not the click issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got to manage the desired output with the help of the answer given by @matty. I also used jquery cookie to retain the viewstate of the sidebar after refreshing the page (post back).

HTML markup is as it is. However, I used the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html, body {
        overflow-x: auto; /* allow scroll */
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    /** Off Canvas **/
    .sidebar-offcanvas, .col-main {
        position: relative;
    }
    .animate .sidebar-offcanvas, .animate .col-main {
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
        transition: all .25s ease-out;
    }
    .side-toggle .sidebar-offcanvas {
        width: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .side-toggle .col-main {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /** Off Canvas **/
    .row-offcanvas {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
        transition: all .25s ease-out;
    }
    .row-offcanvas-right {
        right: 0;
    }
    .row-offcanvas-left {
        left: 0;
    }
    .row-offcanvas-right .sidebar-offcanvas {
        right: -66.66666667%; /* 8 columns */
    }
    .row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -66.66666667%; /* 8 columns */
    }
    .row-offcanvas-right.active {
        right: 66.66666667%; /* 8 columns */
    }
    .row-offcanvas-left.active {
        left: 66.66666667%; /* 8 columns */
    }
    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 66.66666667%; /* 8 columns */
    }
    .row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
}
```

Also, I used [jquery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin to store the collapsed or expanded state of the sidebar in browser cookies. The script I used is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var toggle = $.cookie('toggle');
    if ($(window).width() > 768 && toggle === "hide") {
        $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('side-toggle');
    }
    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active').toggleClass('side-toggle');
        if ($('#sidebar').parent().hasClass('active')) {
            $.cookie('toggle', 'hide');
        }
        if (toggle === "hide") {
            $.removeCookie('toggle');
        }
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $('.row-offcanvas').removeClass('animate');
        } else {
            $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('animate');
        }
        if ($(window).width() > 768 && toggle === "hide") {
            $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('side-toggle');
        }
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

JsBin Edit is [here](http://jsbin.com/gavob/1/edit) and Full screen preview is [here](http://jsbin.com/gavob/1). Please let me know, if you've any doubts/clarifications.

Thanks again **matty** to bring me in the right direction.

Comment: Now it works, so that on the small screen nav is open, and on bigger screen nav is closed, and vice versa. If it is expected behavior then your script is good. Possibly you can move this fragment `if ($(window).width() > 768 && toggle === "hide") {
            $('.row-offcanvas').addClass('side-toggle');
        }` (near the end) outside of window resize function. No need to run this on window resize, it is meant to run only on window load.